# Using jQuery UI dialog and jQuery Tools for apple overlay effect

Tags: jquery, conflict, jquery-tools

I am trying to use jQuery UI for dialogs but I also want to use jQuery Tools to create the apple overlay effect. When both are on the same page the overlay does not work.
Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/XJwgJ/ showing the overlay not working. And here is apple effect code.

```
$(function() {
var $position = 100;
$("#apple img[rel]").overlay({effect: 'apple',left: $position, fixed: false, speed: 'slow'});
jQuery(".apple_overlay").animate({"width": "100px"},
        "slow");
jQuery(".photo2").animate({"width": "100px"},
        "slow");   
});
```

Comment: Check the JavaScript console to see some errors. Fix those and try again.

Comment: Hello @muistooshort I tried again with basic example http://jsfiddle.net/4vZCm/1/ and here is what I learned: when the code  for the dialog is on top and the UI library is under the tools library the dialog works but not the overlay. In opposite when the overlay code is on top and the tools overlay is under UI library the overlay works. Any other combination nothing works. So how do I get them both to work at the same time??

Comment: You still have a "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#apple img[rel]").overlay({effect: 'apple'})')" error. Are you saying that jQuery Tools and jQuery-UI are fighting over `$.fn.overlay`? If that's the case then you have to hack the source to rename `overlay` to something else.

Comment: Thank you, adding `var example=jQuery.noConflict();
example(function(){
example("#apple img[rel]").overlay` worked perfect.